# Is there a jQuery plugin that meets my requirements for multi-form validation?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

That has reg expression checks for phone, zip, email.
Comparison checks for email and password.
Bonus: masking and forcing letters and numbers only options.

I would like one that works well with this:
**http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/**

This is a multistage sign-up and would work when step 1 is complete(the form) it would send it to the server (via url serialized) on valid success go to step 2, which is a sliding div system.

**What is the best way to do this, and combine it inside the above mention ajax form submit plugin's "beforeSubmit" option?**

Comment: The title of your question is misleading. You then go on to ask for a full mutli-part question to your problem.

Comment: saw this new one, ketchup.  looks clean.  http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best validation plugin is Jorns [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). Coupled with the [metadata](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata) plugin it provides a powerful clientside validation framework.

Multipart form demo [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/)

Please go and read and view the examples then ask any specific issues that crop up along the way in your solution.

Comment: Jorns while pretty full-featured on the surface, is still full of bugs like a piece of swiss cheese.

Comment: 2 years later, it's still buggy. The sad thing is that it's about the best thing out there. Has anyone found anything better?

Answer (score 3):

I want my error messages to float independently of my HTML forms.  Here's another validation alternative that looks promising:

https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Answer (score 2):

You can try bValidator: http://code.google.com/p/bvalidator/

Answer (score 0):

I like jQuery tools validator, it uses html 5 input types, support for server validation and a lot of other resources. http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/validator/index.html

Comment: **An early 2013 update:** jQuery Tools validator looks mostly dead at this point - >250 issues, >30 pull requests, and no update to the codebase in nearly a year. It's also being reported as very broken with jQuery 1.9

Comment: That's a shame, jQuery Tools Validator was the easier plug-in that I found. Good to know @Deefour, tks

Comment: I spent a good amount of time looking at alternatives (I used to use jQuery Tools too). I came across https://github.com/rickharrison/validate.js which is framework-agnostic, lightweight, and customizable. Took me all of 30min to replace jQuery Tools this morning.

Comment: Awesome, tks for the advice @Deefour. I'll try this one.