# JQUERY UI - Select Tab based on validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm putting together a Jquery UI Tabbed form with inputs on each tab that require validation.  Ideally I would like to validate the currently visible tab and then select the next tab that does not validate.

What would be the best way to do this?  My code is as follows...

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tab1">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2">Two</a></li>       
        </ul>
        <div id="tab1" >   
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                            Forename</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMainCtcForename" runat="server"  class="required"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                            Surname</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMainCtcSurname" runat="server"  class="required"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                            Email</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMainCtcEmail" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>       
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="ui-tabs-hide">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                            Company Name</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtComName" runat="server"  class="required"></asp:TextBox></li>
                    <li class="blankRow">&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                            Address</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                        </label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                        </label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                        </label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                            Town</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTwn" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                            County</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label class="uiLbl">
                            Postcode</label>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPostcode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT:  Does anyone else have any ideas?  The way I see it I need to...

If the current tab passes validation...

1. Get the control which fails validation
2. Identify the parent tab.
3. Switch to the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use an example I found [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ui-tabs-and-validation-plugin) which highlights tabs that have validation errors.

```
 $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tabs :input").attr("disabled", true);

    });

    $("##ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_submitButton").button();

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#updateLink").click(function () {
            if ($("#updateLink").text() == 'CLICK TO EDIT') {
                $("#updateLink").text("SAVE CHANGES")
                toEditMode();
            } else {

                if ($("#aspnetForm").valid()) {
                    $("#aspnetForm").submit();
                    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_submitButton").click();
                    $("#updateLink").text("CLICK TO EDIT")
                    toDisplayMode();
                }
            }
        });
    });
    function toEditMode() {
        $('#tabs :input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    function toDisplayMode() {
        $("#tabs :input").attr("disabled", true);
    }

    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("submitted!");
        },
        invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
            var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
            if (errors) {
                var invalidPanels = $(validator.invalidElements()).closest(".ui-tabs-panel", form);
                if (invalidPanels.size() > 0) {
                    $.each($.unique(invalidPanels.get()), function () {
                        $(this).siblings(".ui-tabs-nav")
        .find("a[href='#" + this.id + "']").parent().not(".ui-tabs-selected")
          .addClass("ui-state-error")
          .show("pulsate", { times: 3 });
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
            $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").removeClass(errorClass);
            var $panel = $(element).closest(".ui-tabs-panel", element.form);
            if ($panel.size() > 0) {
                if ($panel.find("." + errorClass + ":visible").size() == 0) {
                    $panel.siblings(".ui-tabs-nav").find("a[href='#" + $panel[0].id + "']")
      .parent().removeClass("ui-state-error");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoMultipleForms.html and validate them and the show tab 2 by this way  `$("#tabs").tabs({ selected: 1 });` or you can disable tab 2 by this way  `$('#tabs').tabs('disable', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the jQuery validation plugin you are implementing.
Obviously, you should validate in the server too.

I suggest you to implement the [Jorns jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266084/what-is-the-best-jquery-validation-plugin) (written by a member of the jQuery team):

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

You can see an example of how it works with multiple steps here. In the code you can find the solution:

http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/

They use " a custom method to check if an element is on the current page when validated":

```
    var v = $("#cmaForm").validate({
    errorClass: "warning",
    onkeyup: false,
    onblur: false,      submitHandler: function() {
        alert("Submitted, thanks!");        }   });

$.validator.addMethod("pageRequired", function(value, element) {
        var $element = $(element)
        function match(index) {
            return current == index && $(element)
.parents("#sf" + (index + 1)).length;
        }
        if (match(0) || match(1) || match(2)) {
            return !this.optional(element);
        }
        return "dependency-mismatch";
    }, $.validator.messages.required)
```

In the click event of the button "next" (in your case the tab I suppose) they track the current page, with the variable "current". You should change the "#sf" part for "#tab", and the name of the form "cmaForm".
You should add a click event to the tabs or the buttons to pass from one tab to the other:

```
$("#tab1").click(function() {
          if (v.form()) {   
            current = 0;
          }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using this plugin.  However I'm not using a wizard style form, it's more a tabbed form with a button outside the form to save changes which activates the validation.

Comment: I have added some other comments, you can add this validation event to the tabs, in the same way as it is used in the next/back button of my example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Really, I don't want the changing of tabs to fire validation per say.  My problem is if someone completes the 1st tab and it passes validation and then presses 'save', which fires validation but there is a field that fails validation on tab2.  Currently I ignore invisible elements but I'd rather the active tab switches to the one with the field that doesn't pass validation